# Active Record object reload & reload!?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What is the difference between `active record` `object` `reload` & `send(:reload!)`.

```
self.reload # fetches object attributes from db and modifies current

self.send(:reload!) # doing same ?
```

How to get db object without actually modifying current instance using reload ?

I can do this using -

```
self.class.find self.id
```

is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

from the document:

```
reload!(print=true)
reloads the environment

reload()
Forces reloading of relation.
```

I think reload! is a global function for rib to reload environment, don't sure what will happens in a no-interactive Rails VM...